# (Oracle)Getting multiple column when using correlated subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subquery

My(Scott) goal is to get manager's name ,salary and deptno using correlated subquery.
As below, I could get expected result, but similar subquery has been used several times.
Is there a another neat way(without repeated similar pattern as below)?

```
SELECT
    O.ENAME EMP_NAME
    ,(SELECT DISTINCT FIRST_VALUE(I.ENAME) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL ORDER BY I.SAL DESC)
        FROM SCOTT.EMP I
        WHERE I.EMPNO=O.MGR  --correlated to outer
     ) AS MGR_NAME
     ,(SELECT DISTINCT FIRST_VALUE(I.SAL) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL ORDER BY I.SAL DESC)
        FROM SCOTT.EMP I
        WHERE I.EMPNO=O.MGR  --correlated to outer
     ) AS MGR_SAL
     ,(SELECT DISTINCT FIRST_VALUE(I.DEPTNO) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL ORDER BY I.SAL DESC)
        FROM SCOTT.EMP I
        WHERE I.EMPNO=O.MGR  --correlated to outer
     ) AS MGR_DEPTNO
    from SCOTT.EMP O;
```

Comment: Simple outer join to the `emp` table to get the managers record. Each employee has at most one manager, so performing `FIRST_VALUE` analytic function with a `DISTINCT` seems to be a bit of *overkill*.

Answer (score 2):

```
select  e.ename emp_name, m.ename mgr_name, m.sal mgr_sal, m.deptno mgr_deptno
from    emp e left join emp m
on      e.mgr = m.empno
order   by m.deptno, e.ename;
```

Output:

[image]